# SIMD: Why is the SSE RGB to YUV color conversion about the same speed as the c++ implementation?

Tags: c++, optimization, rgb, yuv, sse2

I've just tried to optimize an RGB to YUV420 converter. Using a lookup table yielded a speed increase, as did using fixed point arithmetic. However I was expecting the real gains using SSE instructions. My first go at it resulted in slower code and after chaining all the operations, it's approximately the same speed as the original code. Is there something wrong in my implementation or are SSE instructions just not suited to the task at hand?

A section of the original code follows:

```
#define RRGB24YUVCI2_00   0.299
#define RRGB24YUVCI2_01   0.587
#define RRGB24YUVCI2_02   0.114
#define RRGB24YUVCI2_10  -0.147
#define RRGB24YUVCI2_11  -0.289
#define RRGB24YUVCI2_12   0.436
#define RRGB24YUVCI2_20   0.615
#define RRGB24YUVCI2_21  -0.515
#define RRGB24YUVCI2_22  -0.100

void RealRGB24toYUV420Converter::Convert(void* pRgb, void* pY, void* pU, void* pV)
{
  yuvType* py = (yuvType *)pY;
  yuvType* pu = (yuvType *)pU;
  yuvType* pv = (yuvType *)pV;
  unsigned char* src = (unsigned char *)pRgb;

  /// Y have range 0..255, U & V have range -128..127.
  double u,v;
  double r,g,b;

  /// Step in 2x2 pel blocks. (4 pels per block).
  int xBlks = _width >> 1;
  int yBlks = _height >> 1;
  for(int yb = 0; yb < yBlks; yb++)
  for(int xb = 0; xb < xBlks; xb++)
  {
    int chrOff = yb*xBlks + xb;
    int lumOff = (yb*_width + xb) << 1;
    unsigned char* t    = src + lumOff*3;

    /// Top left pel.
    b = (double)(*t++);
    g = (double)(*t++);
    r = (double)(*t++);
    py[lumOff] = (yuvType)RRGB24YUVCI2_RANGECHECK_0TO255((int)(0.5 + RRGB24YUVCI2_00*r + RRGB24YUVCI2_01*g + RRGB24YUVCI2_02*b));

    u = RRGB24YUVCI2_10*r + RRGB24YUVCI2_11*g + RRGB24YUVCI2_12*b;
    v = RRGB24YUVCI2_20*r + RRGB24YUVCI2_21*g + RRGB24YUVCI2_22*b;

    /// Top right pel.
    b = (double)(*t++);
    g = (double)(*t++);
    r = (double)(*t++);
    py[lumOff+1] = (yuvType)RRGB24YUVCI2_RANGECHECK_0TO255((int)(0.5 + RRGB24YUVCI2_00*r + RRGB24YUVCI2_01*g + RRGB24YUVCI2_02*b));

    u += RRGB24YUVCI2_10*r + RRGB24YUVCI2_11*g + RRGB24YUVCI2_12*b;
    v += RRGB24YUVCI2_20*r + RRGB24YUVCI2_21*g + RRGB24YUVCI2_22*b;

    lumOff += _width;
    t = t + _width*3 - 6;
    /// Bottom left pel.
    b = (double)(*t++);
    g = (double)(*t++);
    r = (double)(*t++);
    py[lumOff] = (yuvType)RRGB24YUVCI2_RANGECHECK_0TO255((int)(0.5 + RRGB24YUVCI2_00*r + RRGB24YUVCI2_01*g + RRGB24YUVCI2_02*b));

    u += RRGB24YUVCI2_10*r + RRGB24YUVCI2_11*g + RRGB24YUVCI2_12*b;
    v += RRGB24YUVCI2_20*r + RRGB24YUVCI2_21*g + RRGB24YUVCI2_22*b;

    /// Bottom right pel.
    b = (double)(*t++);
    g = (double)(*t++);
    r = (double)(*t++);
    py[lumOff+1] = (yuvType)RRGB24YUVCI2_RANGECHECK_0TO255((int)(0.5 + RRGB24YUVCI2_00*r + RRGB24YUVCI2_01*g + RRGB24YUVCI2_02*b));

    u += RRGB24YUVCI2_10*r + RRGB24YUVCI2_11*g + RRGB24YUVCI2_12*b;
    v += RRGB24YUVCI2_20*r + RRGB24YUVCI2_21*g + RRGB24YUVCI2_22*b;

    /// Average the 4 chr values.
    int iu = (int)u;
    int iv = (int)v;
    if(iu < 0) ///< Rounding.
      iu -= 2;
    else
      iu += 2;
    if(iv < 0) ///< Rounding.
      iv -= 2;
    else
      iv += 2;

    pu[chrOff] = (yuvType)( _chrOff + RRGB24YUVCI2_RANGECHECK_N128TO127(iu/4) );
    pv[chrOff] = (yuvType)( _chrOff + RRGB24YUVCI2_RANGECHECK_N128TO127(iv/4) );
  }//end for xb & yb...
}//end Convert.
```

And here is the version using SSE

```
const float fRRGB24YUVCI2_00 = 0.299;
const float fRRGB24YUVCI2_01 = 0.587;
const float fRRGB24YUVCI2_02 = 0.114;
const float fRRGB24YUVCI2_10 = -0.147;
const float fRRGB24YUVCI2_11 = -0.289;
const float fRRGB24YUVCI2_12 = 0.436;
const float fRRGB24YUVCI2_20 = 0.615;
const float fRRGB24YUVCI2_21 = -0.515;
const float fRRGB24YUVCI2_22 = -0.100;

void RealRGB24toYUV420Converter::Convert(void* pRgb, void* pY, void* pU, void* pV)
{
   __m128 xmm_y = _mm_loadu_ps(fCOEFF_0);
   __m128 xmm_u = _mm_loadu_ps(fCOEFF_1);
   __m128 xmm_v = _mm_loadu_ps(fCOEFF_2);

   yuvType* py = (yuvType *)pY;
   yuvType* pu = (yuvType *)pU;
   yuvType* pv = (yuvType *)pV;
   unsigned char* src = (unsigned char *)pRgb;

   /// Y have range 0..255, U & V have range -128..127.
   float bgr1[4];
   bgr1[3] = 0.0;
   float bgr2[4];
   bgr2[3] = 0.0;
   float bgr3[4];
   bgr3[3] = 0.0;
   float bgr4[4];
   bgr4[3] = 0.0;

   /// Step in 2x2 pel blocks. (4 pels per block).
   int xBlks = _width >> 1;
   int yBlks = _height >> 1;
   for(int yb = 0; yb < yBlks; yb++)
     for(int xb = 0; xb < xBlks; xb++)
     {
       int       chrOff = yb*xBlks + xb;
       int       lumOff = (yb*_width + xb) << 1;
       unsigned char* t    = src + lumOff*3;

       bgr1[2] = (float)*t++;
       bgr1[1] = (float)*t++;
       bgr1[0] = (float)*t++;
       bgr2[2] = (float)*t++;
       bgr2[1] = (float)*t++;
       bgr2[0] = (float)*t++;
       t = t + _width*3 - 6;
       bgr3[2] = (float)*t++;
       bgr3[1] = (float)*t++;
       bgr3[0] = (float)*t++;
       bgr4[2] = (float)*t++;
       bgr4[1] = (float)*t++;
       bgr4[0] = (float)*t++;
       __m128 xmm1 = _mm_loadu_ps(bgr1);
       __m128 xmm2 = _mm_loadu_ps(bgr2);
       __m128 xmm3 = _mm_loadu_ps(bgr3);
       __m128 xmm4 = _mm_loadu_ps(bgr4);

       // Y
       __m128 xmm_res_y = _mm_mul_ps(xmm1, xmm_y);
       py[lumOff] = (yuvType)RRGB24YUVCI2_RANGECHECK_0TO255((xmm_res_y.m128_f32[0] + xmm_res_y.m128_f32[1] + xmm_res_y.m128_f32[2] ));
       // Y
       xmm_res_y = _mm_mul_ps(xmm2, xmm_y);
       py[lumOff + 1] = (yuvType)RRGB24YUVCI2_RANGECHECK_0TO255((xmm_res_y.m128_f32[0]    + xmm_res_y.m128_f32[1] + xmm_res_y.m128_f32[2] ));
       lumOff += _width;
       // Y
       xmm_res_y = _mm_mul_ps(xmm3, xmm_y);
       py[lumOff] = (yuvType)RRGB24YUVCI2_RANGECHECK_0TO255((xmm_res_y.m128_f32[0] + xmm_res_y.m128_f32[1] + xmm_res_y.m128_f32[2] ));
       // Y
       xmm_res_y = _mm_mul_ps(xmm4, xmm_y);
       py[lumOff+1] = (yuvType)RRGB24YUVCI2_RANGECHECK_0TO255((xmm_res_y.m128_f32[0] + xmm_res_y.m128_f32[1] + xmm_res_y.m128_f32[2] ));

       // U
       __m128 xmm_res = _mm_add_ps(
                          _mm_add_ps(_mm_mul_ps(xmm1, xmm_u), _mm_mul_ps(xmm2, xmm_u)),
                          _mm_add_ps(_mm_mul_ps(xmm3, xmm_u), _mm_mul_ps(xmm4, xmm_u))
                       );

       float fU  = xmm_res.m128_f32[0] + xmm_res.m128_f32[1] + xmm_res.m128_f32[2];

       // V
       xmm_res = _mm_add_ps(
      _mm_add_ps(_mm_mul_ps(xmm1, xmm_v), _mm_mul_ps(xmm2, xmm_v)),
      _mm_add_ps(_mm_mul_ps(xmm3, xmm_v), _mm_mul_ps(xmm4, xmm_v))
      );
       float fV  = xmm_res.m128_f32[0] + xmm_res.m128_f32[1] + xmm_res.m128_f32[2];

       /// Average the 4 chr values.
       int iu = (int)fU;
       int iv = (int)fV;
       if(iu < 0) ///< Rounding.
         iu -= 2;
       else
         iu += 2;
       if(iv < 0) ///< Rounding.
         iv -= 2;
       else
         iv += 2;

       pu[chrOff] = (yuvType)( _chrOff + RRGB24YUVCI2_RANGECHECK_N128TO127(iu >> 2) );
       pv[chrOff] = (yuvType)( _chrOff + RRGB24YUVCI2_RANGECHECK_N128TO127(iv >> 2) );
     }//end for xb & yb...
}
```

This is one of my first attempts at SSE2 so perhaps I'm missing something? FYI I am working on the Windows platform using Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A couple of problems:

- you're using misaligned loads - these are quite expensive (apart from on Nehalem aka Core i5/Core i7) - at least 2x the cost of an aligned load - the cost can be amortised if you have plenty of computation after the loads but in this case you have relatively little. You can fix this for the loads from bgr1, bgr2, etc, by making these 16 byte aligned and using aligned loads. [Better yet, don't use these intermediate arrays at all - load data directly from memory to SSE registers and do all your shuffling etc with SIMD - see below]
- you're going back and forth between scalar and SIMD code - the scalar code will probably be the dominant part as far as performance is concerned, so any SIMD gains will tend to be swamped by this - you really need to do **everything** inside your loop using SIMD instructions (i.e. get rid of the scalar code)

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for your answer. I have modified all arrays to be 16 byte aligned now and I'm using _mm_load_ps instead of _mm_loadu_ps. So far I can't see any noticable difference though. With respect to your second suggestion, please excuse my ignorance: how can I avoid switching between the scalar and the SIMD code? I don't understand how I can get rid of the scalar code.

Comment: @Ralf: that's the tricky part, i.e. thinking of SIMD ways to what you might otherwise do with scalar code. Ideally you should load your data directly to SSE registers from memory, then re-organise the elements into the required arrangement, do the calculations, re-organise back into the required output arrangement, then store directly to memory from the SSE register(s). If you have SSSE3 (aka SSE3.5) or better then the shuffling of the elements if a lot easier (PSHUFB) - with SSE3 and earlier it's still possible, but a little trickier, since there are limited shuffle instructions available.

Answer (score 1):

You may use inline assembly instructions instead of insintrics. It may increase the speed of your code a little. But inline assembly is compiler specific. Anyway, as stated in answer by Paul R, you have to use aligned data in order to achieve the full speed. But data alignment is even more compiler specific thing :)

If you can change the compiler, you may try Intel compiler for Windows. I doubt it would be much better, especially for inline assembly code, but it definetely worth looking.

Comment: Hi John, I tried aligning the data, unfortunately to no avail. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Hm.... Did you try only aligning? Because you try to load your data to xmm register by _mm_loadu_ps(float * ) (it maps to MOVUPS instruction), you tell the processor to load unaligned data. It`s not enough to only align data, you have to use appropriate instruction. For your case it is _mm_load_ps(float *) (it maps to MOVAPS instruction). If this function fails, it means that something wrong with your alignment.

Comment: Thanks for your reply John, only saw it now... Yes, I did change all the instructions to use _mm_load_ps but it didn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few problems with your approach:

1. The C++ version loads from pointer t to "double r,g,b", and in all likelihood, the compiler has optimized these into loading to FP registers directly, that is, "double r,g,b" lives in registers at run time. But in your version, you loads into "float bgr0/1/2/3" and then calls _mm_loadu_ps. I won't be surprised if "float bgr0/1/2/3" are in memory, this means you have extra reads and writes to memory.
2. You're using intrinsics instead inline assembly. Some, if not all, of those __m128 variables may still be in memory. Again, extra reads and writes to memory.
3. Most work are probably done in RRGB24YUVCI2_*() and you're not trying to optimize these.

You're not aligning any of your variables, but that's only additional penalty for your extra memory access, try to eliminate these first.

Your best bet is find an existing, optimized RGB/YUV conversion library and use it.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. One question: how would I optimize RRGB24YUVC12_*? You mean I should optimize the range check somehow? Finding an existing optimized library kind of defeats the purpose: the color conversion was just a test to see how SIMD could be applied to video processing algorithms.